# how to restore the hard disk data after gparted deleted them when converting to GPT

Tags: gparted, format, gpt, syslinux

I was trying to install windows 10 when I face a messege want me to convert the partition to GPT .
I used gparted : Device -》create partition table -》then I choose the GPT and in moment I get ALL the partitions deleted

So what is the best solution to get the data again ?

Comment: If the disks haven't been overwritten yet, you can boot with a Live USB/DVD, install [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk/) and [try to recover your partitions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: gpart (not gparted) may also give you a list of the old partitions so you can restore them (assuming they have not been formatted or otherwise overwritten). See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121

Comment: The preceding comments are worthwhile; however, I would also like to point out that the Windows message you saw, although accurate, led you astray. The appropriate action was likely to figure out how to boot the WIndows installation medium in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, not to convert the disk from MBR to GPT.